# Add a character after double in VB

Tags: vb.net

this is my first post on Stack.
I wanted to know if i can add a character after this code to appear on the textbox.
Textbox 2 is the output. I wanted to add the Euro Sign € after the number in the textbox 2 .

```
Dim A As Double
A = TextBox1.Text * 1.5 * 24 / 100
TextBox2.Text = A + TextBox1.Text + 2.5 #this is where i want it to be
```

Comment: can you post your full code. ?  is option strict is on in your file ?

Comment: @Cal-cium, this will fail if option `strict` is on

Comment: First read [ask] and take the [tour], then set `Option Strict On`, then if you want to know if you can do something *try it*.

Comment: @UsmanRana I think we can assume he hasnt got it on as he hasn't converted his textbox1.text into the variable `A`

Comment: what is 2.5 ? do you want to add it in your result or it's just to concatinate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Option Strict` is on, which it should be. The below should work.
to get the 2.5 to output as string you will have to put it in "" or do something with it before hand. E.g.

```
Dim A As Double
A = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 1.5 * 24 / 100
TextBox2.Text = A.ToString() + TextBox1.Text + "2.5" + "€"
```

Or

```
Dim A As Double
A = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 1.5 * 24 / 100
Dim x As String = CType(2.5, String)
TextBox2.Text = A.ToString() + TextBox1.Text + x + "€"
```

Or  if you want to total variable A and textbox2.text and 2.5 and then concatenate with euro sign. To do this you must first add them into a variable so that conversions are done correctly and then output them to the textbox2 with the euro sign at the end.

```
Dim A As Double 
A = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 1.5 * 24 / 100 
Dim x as Double = A + CDbl(TextBox1.Text) + 2.5 
TextBox2.Text =  x.ToString() +"€"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that textbox1.text Is a number , so that just gives me the number that comes out of A with the number in the textbox1 and the euro sign

Comment: TextBox1.Text is a String.  It may be a string representation of a number, but it's a String.  You should compile with Option Strict On and explicitly convert the string to whatever numeric type you expect instead of letting VB   do it for you.  The reason being that allowing that will often mask serious flaws that would be obvious with Option Strict On.

Comment: @SeaZz Are you wanting to add all these values together then and then output that with the euro sign? For example, if `A = 1` and `TextBox1.Text = 2`. in this scenario you would want 1 + 2 + 2.5 added up and then put a euro sign, so that `TextBox2.Text` outputted 5.5€?  or do you want what I've already put in my answer, where it outputs the number from A with the number in TextBox1 and the euro sign?

Comment: @Cal-cium First Scenario where i have a double (float) value and output to the textbox2.The value with the sign together

Answer (score 0):

`+` and `&` these are two concatenation operators in `vb.net`. But when you specify and integer using `+`, it tries to cast the input `A + TextBox1.Text` to `integer` and if it of something like "ABCD", which can not be convertable/castable to `integer` but if it is something like "1234", your good to go and you can use

```
TextBox2.Text = A + TextBox1.Text + 2.5 + "€"
```